# C# Transfer data from one database to another database through datagridviews

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have to allot work for my volunteers. Here I have two Databases as follows

**Database1-**(Having 3 Columns as)

---

> Name |    Designation | Living

---

**Database 2** (Having 4 Columns as)

> Name  | Designation | Living |    ToWork

***My Winform has two ComboBoxes, two datagridviews and two buttons between two datagridviews***

1. ComboBox1 – (RawSource from Database1, Living Column Values)
2. DatagridView1 displays the result of (ComboBox1 changed) data from Database1 based on selected Living Column rows

a.  ComboBox2 – (RawSource from Database2 , ToWork Column Values)

b.  DatagridView2 displays the result of (ComboBo2 changed) data from Database2 based on selected ToWork Column rows

Here I have  are two Button.One button transfer selected data from one datagridview to another datagridview. Here I need code which transfer selected row data from one datagridview to another datagridview at the same time database to database. (Eg. I***f selected rows of datagridview1 transferred to datagridview2 at the same time the data also transferred to database1 to database2 vice versa…***)

How can I get this… Any help or guide would be appreciate and thankful….

Comment: It almost seems like you are asking how to do this is the hardest possible way.  But for certain, there is nothing there showing any effort of giving anyone a starting point.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

UI controls for display data you can easily do it via sql query,load from database 1 and insert into database2